# What's the advantage of using mainnet over testnet for contract tokens?

Tags: ether, testnets, tokens, contract-deployment

Let's say that I crowdfund a project by selling shares in form of tokens on the Ethereum platform to investors. It seems that I can do this on the testnet without any disadvantage.

Are real Ether needed for this situation? Is the idea that my shares must only be sold for real Ether on the mainnet and not any other currency?

If so, how is that enforced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no guarantee the testnet will be around.  Testnets may get reset.**

Furthermore, the mining hashrate on testnets are also much lower than mainnet, so there is **virtually no security**.

For these reasons, people are unlikely to buy any testnet tokens.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the main net if you want the proof-of-work security provided by miners. If you use a testnet, it is trivial for an attacker to double spend your crowdfund tokens.